# C++ CRTP Base class cannot return type defined in the derived class

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

I'm using CRTP and I'd like the Base class to implement a static method, where the return type is determined by the sub class:

```
template<class Derived>
struct Base
{
    static typename Derived::T getSomething()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
  using T = int;  
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.getSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

However, the problem is at the time the Base class is constructed, the Derived class obviously hasn't been constructed either, giving an incomplete type:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct Base<Derived>’:
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.cpp',22)">main.cpp:22:25</span>:   required from here
main.cpp:16:32: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Derived’
   16 |     static typename Derived::T getSomething()
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:22:8: note: forward declaration of ‘struct Derived’
   22 | struct Derived : public Base<Derived>
      |        ^~~~~~~
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:31:7: error: ‘struct Derived’ has no member named ‘getSomething’
   31 |     d.getSomething();
```

Is there another way to achieve this? My sub classes have different types, can have different behavior but when they don't, I wish to use a common implementation in the base class.

Comment: Use a deduced type `auto` and `return typename Derived::T{};`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts  I put the return type as `auto` and returned `typename Derived::T{};` but got `main.cpp:16:12: error: ‘getSomething’ function uses ‘auto’ type specifier without trailing return type`. Can you reword?

Comment: Sounds like you're using C++11, not C++20

Comment: Online compiler needed additional flag. Thanks!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik not a great duplicate since that one requires the dependent type as a function parameter, not a return type. The solution for a return type doesn't require making the CRTP base class method a template.